Searching for a QuickBasic 2.0 book (not 4.5)
I'm travelling now to 1986, and trying the 2.0 version of QuickBasic on a 80286, emulated in PCem. (DOS version 3.2)
So this question is not about QBASIC, but about QuickBasic.
All the books I find on QuickBasic are about 4.5. It's super hard to find any earlier ones.
This is the only one I found, but it is about 1.01, and the scan is sloppy. (Some pages are in bad order, etc.)
https://archive.org/details/microsoft-quick-basic-1.01-manual
If I use the manuals for 4.5, then I often run into either missing features or statements that were different in 2.0.
Now I discovered that I can use books written for late GW-Basic too, as the similarity is high. But I would love to find a full reference guide to QuickBasic 2.x.
Many thanks!

Have you looked at the Douglas Hergert book? It was published in 1987 although this might be too late for the version you want, and was published by Microsoft even though it's not the manual.

@NoelWhitemore Thanks! I didn't see that. Had a look, and it looks good: I tried some code in it and all worked in 2.0.

Yes, in all examples that have data per year, the last year is always 1986. So he probably worked on the book mostly in 1986. Cool.
